# Centering in a Tabular Environment with Preset width

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a simple question that seemingly has no simple answer.

With the code below:

```
\begin{center}
    \huge
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
        \textsf{\emph{\textbf{x}}} &   \textsf{\emph{\textbf{y}}}\\
             \hline
             0 & 1 \\
             \hline
             1& 3 \\
             \hline
             2& 5 \\
             \hline
             3 & 7\\
             \hline
             4 & 9 \\
             \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
```

How do I add a preset width of 2cm to each column, while keeping everything in the cells centered? Additionally, **how do I do this without making any new commands?**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you could edit your question into a small document that can be compiled so that people only have to copy/paste your question to find solutions, whilst your question is not too difficult, in the future could you start with `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` please

Comment: Please clarify whether 2cm should be the usable width or the total width of the columns.

Answer (score 5):

[`array`](//ctan.org/pkg/array) provides a column specification `w{<align>}{<width>}` that you can use. Specifically, the columns would use `w{c}{2cm}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \huge
  \begin{tabular}{ | w{c}{2cm} | w{c}{2cm} | }
    \hline
    \textsf{\emph{\textbf{x}}} & \textsf{\emph{\textbf{y}}}\\
    \hline
    0 & 1 \\
    \hline
    1 & 3 \\
    \hline
    2 & 5 \\
    \hline
    3 & 7 \\
    \hline
    4 & 9 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Learning something new everyday. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a key `columns-width`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \huge
        \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|}[columns-width=2cm]
            \hline
        \textsf{\emph{\textbf{x}}} &   \textsf{\emph{\textbf{y}}}\\
             \hline
             0 & 1 \\
             \hline
             1& 3 \\
             \hline
             2& 5 \\
             \hline
             3 & 7\\
             \hline
             4 & 9 \\
             \hline
        \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

Your query leaves open whether `2cm` should be the usable or the total  width of the column.

- If it's the *usable* column width, one may use `2cm` directly in the second argument of the `w` column type; see [@Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678700/5001).
- If, conversely, `2cm` is supposed to be the *total* column width, one may continue to use the `w` column type, but one now has to subtract `2\tabcolsep` from `2cm` to obtain the usable column width; see below for an example of how this may be done.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type
\newcommand\zzz{%
  \hline
  \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} \\ \hline
  0 & 1 \\ \hline
  2 & 3 \\ \hline}
  
\newlength\mylen % set up a scratch length parameter 

\begin{document}

\verb+c+ col.\ type\strut
 
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
   \zzz
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\verb+w+ col.\ type, 2cm \emph{usable} width\strut

\begin{tabular}{| w{c}{2cm} | w{c}{2cm} |}
   \zzz
\end{tabular}  

\bigskip
\verb+w+ col.\ type, 2cm \emph{total} width\strut

\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr2cm-2\tabcolsep\relax} % compute the usable width
\begin{tabular}{| w{c}{\mylen} | w{c}{\mylen} |}
   \zzz
\end{tabular} 

\smallskip
\addtolength\tabcolsep{1em} % enlarge value of \tabcolsep
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr2cm-2\tabcolsep\relax} % recompute the usable width
\begin{tabular}{| w{c}{\mylen} | w{c}{\mylen} |}
   \zzz
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```